# Want to payout money to another bank account using stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

My requirement is to pay out money directly to the user, users will provide their bank account and money will be directly transferred to their given bank account number.
Bank details will be provided by the user and it's not fixed every time. so I cant manually add a bank account to stripe.
in this context, I am using TokenBankAccountOptions in stripe and written the following code for bank account create.

```
var options = new TokenCreateOptions
        {
            BankAccount = new TokenBankAccountOptions
            {
                Country = "US",
                Currency = "usd",
                AccountHolderName = "Jenny Rosen",
                AccountHolderType = "individual",
                RoutingNumber = "110000000",
                AccountNumber = "000123456789",
            },
        };
        var service = new TokenService();
        Token striptoken = await service.CreateAsync(options);
        await Transfer(striptoken.Id);
```

Now I want to transfer or payout money to a given bank account but the stripe not taking any bank details in payout options or transfer options.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have to use `Stripe Connect` for this

Comment: yes, I have a stripe account of my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sinanspd mentioned, you need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/) for this, and I'd also recommend [checking with Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) to make sure your use case is supported.

Comment: I don't want to connect the account manually on stripe. user will provide account details on the UI, where payment will be made. is it possible with Stripe Connect.

Comment: I have read this article it's asking for CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID but account detail will be provided by the user on UI.

Comment: You need to have them connect their Stripe Account to yours: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts

Comment: this solution is opening a stripe account for a customer, but I want to transfer the amount to a customer's bank account. is that possible?

Comment: No it's not.  Support can provide you with more details if you need them.

Comment: @Manoj did you find the solution for this? I'm having the same problem which user provides account details on the UI. I would appreciate if you can help me with this